# Atomic update of data structure in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

I am using typescript and the Firebase Realtime Database (cannot use Firestore), and I have data in the form on an interface MyData as follows:

```
enum RunStatus {
    RUNNING,
    ENDED
}

interface IResults {
    firstItem: string;
    secondItem: number;
}

interface MyData {
    status: RunStatus;
    results: IResults;
}
```

Suppose I have 10 clients that might end up writing this data simultaneously to (1) change status from RUNNING to ENDED and (2) set the results field.

What I want is for only the first client to be able to do this, so I need to use a transaction of some sort.

My data is stored at this path: "/some/path/here/mydata".

As near as I can tell from the limited documentation, my writes should look something like this:

```
class MyDatabase {
    db: Database;

    constructor(db_: Database) {
        this.db = db_
    }

    writeMyData(newData: MyData) {
        const path="/some/path/here/mydata";
        const reference=child(ref(this.db),path);
        runTransaction(reference, (currentData) => {
            if (currentData) {
                if (currentData.status!=RunStatus.ENDED && newData.status==RunStatus.ENDED) {
                    currentData.status=newData.status;
                    currentData.results=newData.results;
                    // Or, I could have just set currentData=newData
                }
            }
            return currentData;
        });
    }
}
```

Is this correct? And what exactly does it do if multiple clients try to run this at the same time? The documentation says something about runTransaction being automatically rerun if currentData is updated by another client while the first client is writing. Can someone please explain to me if this is correct, and what is happening here?

Comment: The code looks fine to me at first glance. What is your specific concern? Without knowing specifics, it's unlikely we can explain better than the documentation does: i.e. when there are multiple concurrent writes, they get retried.

Comment: Why not lock it with security rules? Forbid changing `results` unless the current status is RUNNING and the new status is ENDED. Then if another user tries to override the result, they get knocked back. This allows you to skip using transactions entirely.